# How does the iOS app customize the height of the navigation?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How does the iOS app customize the height of the navigation? For example, the current system navigation height 44, want to change to 100. thanks

Xcode 11.1, iOS 13.1

Comment: Do you mean the height of the navigation bar?

Comment: Yes, it is said that the navigation bar frame can be modified directly before iOS11.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible but its not something what apple will approve when you send the app to the store rather than changing the height of the navigation bar you could make the bar view transparent and add a UIView which has the content.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a custom navigation height won't pass the review process on the App Store. If you want a large `NavigationBar` you could always set the Bar to large titles:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

[Apple docs for large titles](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/2908999-preferslargetitles)

Comment: Please note that the question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift. Answers should be posted in the appropriate language.